# Detected package downgrade

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nuget

I created two packages. Those two packages are in version 0.0.1. Package B*.A*.Application references B*.Application. B*.Application is in 0.0.1 and B*.A*.Application is also in 0.0.1. But when I installed in another project, compiler says B*.A*.Application needs B*.Application >= 1.0.0. I've never said it needs 1.0.0, and those two projects are in 0.0.1. B*.A*.Application just references it. Maybe I could lock it but I couldn't find it where.

I don't know where compiler is getting this information - it needs >= 1.0.0.

I know when you don't have package control, you just need to update it but the problem is: I created those packages and I've never said it needs 1.0.0

Thank you guys!

[image]

Comment: Almost certainly you created `B*.Application` with the default 1.0.0 version and referenced that version from `B*.A*.Application`, then later updated `B*.Application` to 0.0.1 without recompiling `B*.A*.Application` so it knows about the updated dependency.

Comment: Hey Ian. Yea, I created with 1.0.0, but I recompiled. I deleted it bin/obj folders too. I've already did almost everything. I don't know what to do anymore lol